# Primefaces filedownload no descarga

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Buenas tardes, tengo una aplicación donde uso Primefaces, ManagedBeans, Spring y Hibernate, estoy haciendo un botón para poder descargar un archivo PDF pasando como parámetro la ruta.
Haciendo Debug, veo que si ejecuta, pero el stream lo regresa Null, he estado buscando otras preguntas parecidas por acá pero no me funcionan, me he asegurado que la ruta y el archivo existen, pero no descarga el archivo, acá mi código

ManagedBean

```
    public void descargarFormato(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws Exception {

        String fileName = (String)actionEvent.getComponent().getAttributes().get("fileName");
        File file = new File(fileName);
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
        ExternalContext externalContext = 
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        setArchivoDescarga(new DefaultStreamedContent(input, externalContext.getMimeType(file.getName()), file.getName()));

    }
```

Mi XHTML

```html
<h:form id="formaUpdate" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p:commandButton value="DESCARGAR ARCHIVO" ayax="false" update="formaUpdate" actionListener="#{resguardoMB.descargarFormato}">
 <p:fileDownload value="#{resguardoMB.archivoDescarga}" />
 <f:attribute name="fileName" value="#{resguardoMB.rutaFormato}"/>
</p:commandButton>
</h:form>

Les agradezco mucho
```

[image: Este es el resultado del Debug]

Este es el código completo de mi XHTML:

```html
<h:form id="formaUpdate" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true" />
     <h1>ACTUALIZAR RESGUARDO</h1>
     
     <input type="hidden" name="nombreUserLog" id="nombreUserLog" value="#{loginMB.nombre}" />
     
     <h:inputHidden id="idResguardo" value="#{resguardoMB.idResguardo}"/>
     <h:inputHidden id="rutaFormato" value="#{resguardoMB.rutaFormato}"/>
     <h:inputHidden id="nombreUserLogEdit" value="#{loginMB.nombre}"/>
     
     <p:panel header="Adicionales">
     <p:panelGrid columns="4" layout="grid" style="width: 100%" cellpadding="5" styleClass="alignLeft">
     
      <h:outputLabel for="numSeMaletaLaptop" value="Maleta Laptop " />
      <h:outputLabel for="numSeCandadoLaptop" value="Candado Laptop " />
      <h:outputLabel for="numSeVideoCam" value="Video Cámara " />
      <h:outputLabel for="numSeCamDigital" value="Cámara Digital " />
      
      <p:inputText id="numSeMaletaLaptop" value="#{resguardoMB.numSeMaletaLaptop}"></p:inputText>
      <p:inputText id="numSeCandadoLaptop" value="#{resguardoMB.numSeCandadoLaptop}"></p:inputText> 
      <p:inputText id="numSeVideoCam" value="#{resguardoMB.numSeVideoCam}"></p:inputText>
      <p:inputText id="numSeCamDigital" value="#{resguardoMB.numSeCamDigital}"></p:inputText>
      
      <h:outputLabel for="numSeVideoProy" value="Video Proyector " />
      <h:outputLabel for="numSeMemoriaUsb" value="Memoria USB " />
      <h:outputLabel for="numSeTelCelu" value="Teléfono Celular " />
      <h:outputLabel for="numSeOtroEquipo" value="Otro Equipo " />
      
      <p:inputText id="numSeVideoProy" value="#{resguardoMB.numSeVideoProy}" ></p:inputText>
      <p:inputText id="numSeMemoriaUsb" value="#{resguardoMB.numSeMemoriaUsb}"></p:inputText>
      <p:inputText id="numSeTelCelu" value="#{resguardoMB.numSeTelCelu}"></p:inputText>
      <p:inputText id="numSeOtroEquipo" value="#{resguardoMB.numSeOtroEquipo}" ></p:inputText>
      
      <h:outputLabel for="comentarios" value="Comentarios " />
      <h:outputLabel></h:outputLabel>
      <h:outputLabel></h:outputLabel>
      <h:outputLabel></h:outputLabel>
      
      <p:inputTextarea id="comentarios" rows="5" cols="30" value="#{resguardoMB.comentarios}" counter="contador" maxlength="150" counterTemplate="{0} caracteres restantes. " autoResize="false" />
         <p:commandButton value="ACTUALIZAR" action="#{resguardoMB.updateResguardo}" update="growl"></p:commandButton>
      <p:commandButton rendered="#{loginMB.resguardo_rol eq ('SUPERADMIN' or 'ADMIN')}" value="DESCARGAR ARCHIVO" ayax="false" >
       <p:fileDownload value="#{fileDownloadView.file}" />
      </p:commandButton>
      <p:button value="INICIO" outcome="index"></p:button>
                     
         <h:outputText id="contador" /> 
         <h:outputLabel></h:outputLabel>
      <h:outputLabel></h:outputLabel>
      <h:outputLabel></h:outputLabel>
      
     </p:panelGrid>
         <p:fileUpload id="archivoFormato" rendered="#{loginMB.resguardo_rol eq ('SUPERADMIN' or 'ADMIN')}" fileUploadListener="#{resguardoMB.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" update="growl" multiple="false"
                   sizeLimit="1048576"
                   allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(pdf)$/"
                   uploadLabel="Cargar" cancelLabel="Cancelar" label="Buscar archivo"/>
               <h:outputLabel></h:outputLabel> 
     </p:panel>
     </h:form>
```

Gracias

Comment: Prueba quitarle el actionListener del boton y ponlo en el value del p:fileDownload  resguardoMB.descargarFormato prueba asi me cuentas

Comment: Gracias por constestar, no estoy seguro si te entendí, te refieres a hacer esto?  <p:commandButton value="DESCARGAR ARCHIVO" ayax="false" update="formaUpdate" >
       <p:fileDownload actionListener="#{resguardoMB.descargarFormato}" />
       <f:attribute name="fileName" value="#{resguardoMB.rutaFormato}"/>
      </p:commandButton>

Comment: <p:commandButton value="DESCARGAR ARCHIVO" ayax="false" update="formaUpdate" >
 <p:fileDownload value="#{resguardoMB.descargarFormato}" />
 <f:attribute name="fileName" value="#{resguardoMB.rutaFormato}"/>
</p:commandButton> prueba de esta manera

Comment: Gracias @Raul Cacacho hice el cambio, también cambié mi método para recibir el String que se envía, pero sigue sin descargar, manda null en el InputStream, pondré una imagen de los valores que manda en el Debug

Comment: Subi la imagen del Debug @RaulCacacho esto es después de hacer el cambio, si pasa bien el parametro y llama al método, también existe la ruta y el archivo

Comment: ahi veo q no le estas setteando la dirección del archivo, tambien podrias pegar aqui el log del error

Comment: File temp = File.createTempFile("i-am-a-temp-file", ".tmp" );
String fileName = temp.getAbsolutePath(); prueba esta manera me cuentas

Comment: Asi quedó mi ManagedBean después de lo que me comentaste   File temp = File.createTempFile("i-am-a-temp-file", ".tmp" ); 
  String fileName = temp.getAbsolutePath();
  File file = new File(fileName);
     InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
     ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
     setArchivoDescarga(new DefaultStreamedContent(input, externalContext.getMimeType(file.getName()), file.getName()));     Pero sigue sin descargar, igual manda null el stream, si toma la ruta, pero hace el mismo comportamiento que lo anterior

Comment: Estaba revisando y nos falta el tipo de archivo que vas a descargar puedes hacerlo asi String contentType = "application/pdf";  externalContext .setResponseContentType(contentType);

Comment: Ya se lo agregué, pero igual no descarga, cuando pido todos los atributos del archivo si los manda, como file.isFile(). El problema es al guardarlo en el InputStream, ahi ya no lo hace

Comment: y si lo haces como esta forma con un Files.copy aqui te lo dejo File file = new File("/path/to/file.ext");
String fileName = file.getName();
String contentType = ec.getMimeType(fileName); // JSF 1.x: ((ServletContext) ec.getContext()).getMimeType(fileName);
int contentLength = (int) file.length();

// ...

Files.copy(file.toPath(), output);

Comment: Genial. Me ha servido el consejo. Hice un copy al archivo y lo pasé a la carpeta resources de mi aplicación, solo así ya se llena el stream. Pero aun no se descarga el archivo. Me parece que no está haciendo el refresh a la pagina. Voy a poner el codigo como ha quedado del bean y el jsf.

Comment: Prueba poner la ruta del archivo con con doble diagonal así //

Comment: Aun no logro resolverlo, pero me he dado cuenta que el problema no está en el ManagedBean, ya encuentra el archivo, pero no lo descarga aparentemente porque está en un form con otros botones, asumo esto porque hice una prueba poniendo el botón de Descarga solo en una página y llamando el mismo ManagedBean si lo descarga, cuando abro la consola de JavaScript, me aparece este error: Request return with error:parsererror. Alguien sabe si es porque está con otros botones que si usan ayax?

Comment: Podrias copiarme aqui el boton quiero ver como lo tenes

Comment: Claro, voy a Actualizar la pregunta con mi código completo del XHTML

Comment: Listo @RaulCacacho, ya puse mi código completo, con los demás botones

Comment: Prueba de esta manera es el ajax que utilizo yo <p:commandButton rendered="#{loginMB.resguardo_rol eq ('SUPERADMIN' or 'ADMIN')}" value="DESCARGAR ARCHIVO"  
onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop);" update="@form">
<p:fileDownload value="#{fileDownloadView.file}" />
      </p:commandButton>

Comment: Genial!!! Ya funcionó al fin. Te debo una, el problema ahora lo entiendo, estaba combinando ayax = false con update=forma, ahora integraré lo demás del código para poner la respuesta acá. Muchas gracias @RaulCacacho

Comment: Buenisimo q te funciono si pon la respuesta aca abajo

Comment: Como tienes declarada la variable rutaFormato dentro del bean, siempre me llega null y se revienta. La declare String y coloque el h:inputHidden en la pagina. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despues de las pruebas que hiciste te funciono agregar al boton estas lineas que son ajax de primefaces 
**onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop);" update="@form"**

```
<p:commandButton rendered="#{loginMB.resguardo_rol eq ('SUPERADMIN' or   'ADMIN')}" value="DESCARGAR ARCHIVO" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop);" update="@form">
                        <p:fileDownload value="#{fileDownloadView.file}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

Como bien lo menciona Raul, el problema eran las instrucciones ajax, estaba combinando ayax="false" y update="formaUpdate", al final solamente usé update="@form" para actualizar la forma, y ya descarga, aunque ahora tengo otro problema relacionado, pero eso irá en otro post, el código quedó así:
Mi XHTML

```html
<h:inputHidden id="rutaFormato" value="#{resguardoMB.rutaFormato}"/>

<p:commandButton value="DESCARGAR ARCHIVO" actionListener="#{resguardoMB.descargarFormato}" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop);" update="@form">
       <p:fileDownload value="#{resguardoMB.archivoDescarga}" />
      </p:commandButton>
```

Mi ManagedBean
Como verán también tuve que copiar el archivo dentro de la carpeta resources de mi aplicación porque no lo tomaba de la ruta externa

```
public void descargarFormato() throws Exception {

    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    String rutaFormatoasign = ec.getRequestParameterMap().get("formaUpdate:rutaFormato");

    File origen = new File(rutaFormatoasign);
    String nombre = origen.getName();
    File destino = new File("C:/RutaWebApp/resources/" + "archivoDescarga.pdf");

    try {
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(origen);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destino);

            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;

            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }

            in.close();
            out.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    rutaFormato = rutaFormatoasign;
    InputStream stream = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream("/resources/" + "archivoDescarga.pdf");
    setArchivoDescarga(new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "application/pdf", nombre));
}
```